# plotting rows frequency of a column against the rows in r

Tags: r

I have a file with 2 column index and data where index is of integer type and data is of string type (character type in R).index are unique value where as **data has many duplicates rows**. **the file has more than 2 million rows so I can't see each unique value in the console by printing unique value**. how can I get the frequency of each unique rows and plot it against the unique rows itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `barplot`.

```
(r <- with(df, table(data)) )
# data
#   a   b   c   d   e 
#  27 116 199 284 374 

barplot(r, ylab='Freq', main='Dupes')
```

[image]

---

*Data:*

```
df <- structure(list(index = 1:1000, data = c("b", "b", "e", "c", "d", 
"d", "c", "e", "c", "c", "d", "c", "b", "e", "d", "b", "a", "e", 
"d", "d", "b", "e", "a", "b", "e", "d", "d", "b", "d", "c", "c", 
"c", "d", "c", "e", "c", "e", "e", "b", "d", "d", "d", "e", "a", 
"d", "b", "b", "d", "a", "d", "e", "e", "d", "c", "e", "c", "c", 
"e", "e", "d", "c", "a", "c", "d", "c", "e", "e", "c", "c", "e", 
"e", "e", "e", "d", "e", "c", "e", "d", "d", "e", "d", "e", "d", 
"c", "c", "d", "e", "e", "e", "e", "c", "e", "e", "b", "b", "c", 
"e", "d", "c", "d", "d", "e", "e", "d", "b", "b", "c", "c", "d", 
"e", "d", "c", "c", "d", "d", "d", "e", "e", "d", "c", "e", "d", 
"d", "d", "c", "d", "b", "b", "e", "c", "b", "d", "d", "b", "c", 
"d", "c", "e", "c", "d", "e", "e", "d", "c", "c", "c", "e", "b", 
"e", "e", "c", "e", "c", "d", "c", "c", "e", "e", "e", "c", "b", 
"d", "d", "e", "d", "e", "d", "e", "e", "e", "c", "d", "d", "d", 
"d", "e", "c", "d", "c", "c", "b", "b", "e", "e", "c", "c", "b", 
"c", "e", "e", "e", "c", "e", "e", "e", "e", "d", "e", "c", "c", 
"b", "d", "c", "d", "e", "d", "a", "d", "e", "e", "d", "c", "e", 
"e", "d", "c", "d", "e", "d", "b", "d", "e", "d", "b", "e", "c", 
"e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "a", "c", "e", "b", "d", 
"d", "e", "d", "e", "e", "d", "d", "e", "e", "d", "b", "e", "e", 
"e", "d", "e", "c", "e", "d", "d", "d", "c", "e", "e", "b", "d", 
"e", "b", "e", "b", "b", "e", "c", "d", "e", "b", "e", "e", "d", 
"d", "d", "d", "e", "e", "a", "e", "e", "d", "e", "e", "e", "b", 
"c", "e", "d", "e", "e", "c", "d", "e", "e", "d", "d", "e", "e", 
"b", "b", "d", "e", "e", "e", "e", "a", "d", "e", "e", "b", "e", 
"c", "b", "a", "d", "d", "e", "e", "d", "b", "d", "c", "c", "c", 
"b", "e", "e", "d", "c", "d", "d", "e", "c", "e", "d", "e", "c", 
"d", "e", "e", "b", "d", "c", "b", "d", "d", "e", "e", "c", "d", 
"c", "b", "d", "d", "d", "c", "e", "a", "c", "d", "d", "b", "d", 
"e", "e", "e", "c", "e", "c", "a", "e", "e", "e", "c", "d", "d", 
"d", "e", "d", "c", "e", "b", "e", "e", "b", "d", "c", "e", "c", 
"d", "a", "b", "d", "e", "e", "d", "d", "d", "b", "e", "a", "e", 
"e", "d", "e", "d", "e", "c", "e", "e", "e", "c", "d", "e", "e", 
"d", "a", "c", "d", "e", "d", "e", "c", "d", "d", "d", "d", "e", 
"b", "e", "d", "e", "e", "d", "c", "b", "d", "c", "e", "d", "e", 
"c", "c", "e", "d", "d", "c", "c", "d", "e", "e", "c", "b", "c", 
"d", "e", "c", "e", "e", "d", "e", "e", "d", "b", "e", "e", "b", 
"b", "d", "d", "d", "b", "e", "c", "e", "d", "c", "e", "b", "d", 
"b", "e", "e", "e", "a", "d", "c", "d", "d", "e", "c", "e", "e", 
"e", "e", "e", "d", "c", "e", "b", "d", "e", "b", "e", "e", "c", 
"e", "e", "d", "e", "e", "e", "e", "d", "c", "b", "c", "e", "c", 
"c", "e", "b", "d", "e", "c", "e", "c", "c", "d", "e", "e", "d", 
"d", "e", "c", "b", "d", "e", "d", "c", "c", "e", "e", "e", "b", 
"e", "c", "e", "e", "e", "b", "e", "b", "c", "c", "e", "e", "e", 
"e", "e", "c", "e", "d", "c", "d", "e", "a", "e", "e", "d", "e", 
"e", "d", "d", "e", "b", "c", "c", "e", "d", "a", "a", "d", "c", 
"e", "c", "d", "a", "c", "d", "d", "e", "e", "d", "d", "e", "c", 
"e", "d", "d", "c", "e", "d", "d", "d", "d", "c", "e", "c", "b", 
"e", "e", "d", "e", "d", "d", "e", "c", "e", "c", "e", "d", "c", 
"d", "e", "e", "e", "e", "d", "c", "e", "d", "c", "c", "e", "e", 
"d", "c", "d", "c", "d", "e", "a", "b", "e", "b", "b", "c", "d", 
"d", "e", "e", "d", "e", "c", "b", "e", "c", "e", "c", "d", "d", 
"c", "e", "d", "c", "e", "d", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "d", "d", 
"b", "c", "b", "e", "c", "e", "e", "c", "d", "d", "e", "b", "c", 
"e", "c", "d", "b", "b", "d", "c", "d", "e", "c", "c", "c", "e", 
"e", "e", "d", "b", "b", "d", "c", "c", "c", "d", "e", "e", "c", 
"e", "d", "e", "d", "e", "c", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "b", "a", 
"b", "e", "d", "e", "c", "d", "b", "b", "d", "d", "b", "b", "d", 
"e", "c", "b", "d", "e", "e", "d", "e", "e", "e", "d", "e", "b", 
"b", "a", "c", "e", "e", "c", "c", "b", "d", "d", "d", "d", "e", 
"d", "e", "c", "e", "b", "b", "c", "b", "d", "c", "d", "e", "c", 
"e", "e", "d", "d", "e", "b", "d", "c", "e", "d", "e", "d", "e", 
"c", "e", "b", "b", "e", "d", "d", "e", "d", "e", "e", "d", "e", 
"b", "d", "d", "c", "d", "b", "e", "e", "d", "e", "c", "d", "e", 
"e", "b", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "d", "e", "d", "d", "d", "e", 
"c", "b", "e", "c", "c", "e", "d", "d", "e", "e", "e", "c", "e", 
"d", "c", "e", "d", "c", "e", "d", "b", "d", "b", "a", "c", "e", 
"e", "e", "c", "e", "e", "d", "e", "c", "b", "e", "c", "d", "c", 
"e", "d", "b", "d", "b", "c", "d", "c", "b", "e", "e", "e", "c", 
"c", "e", "d", "d", "d", "d", "b", "d", "e", "c", "c", "e", "e", 
"d", "e", "d", "b", "e", "e", "d", "e", "d", "e", "b", "b", "c", 
"c", "a", "d", "e", "e", "c", "a", "a", "e", "d", "b", "e", "d", 
"e", "d", "d", "b", "b", "b", "c", "e", "e", "e", "e", "c", "d", 
"d", "e", "e", "c", "d", "e", "c", "d", "e", "e", "d", "e", "c", 
"d", "d", "d", "c", "c", "c", "d", "c", "e", "c", "e", "b", "e", 
"e", "c", "e", "d", "d", "d", "d", "e", "e", "e", "d", "c", "e", 
"d", "e", "d", "c", "d", "e", "b", "e", "e", "b", "c", "e", "c", 
"b", "e", "e", "d", "e", "d", "e")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1000L))
```

Comment: this is giving better result..thank you...anyway to change the bandwidth

Answer (score 0):

Assuming something like:

```
df <- data.frame(
    index = 1:200,
    data = sample(letters, 200, replace = TRUE)
)
```

Using the `table()` function you can easily get the frequencies:

```
> table(df$data)
 a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  k  l  m  n  o  p  q  r  s  t  u  v 
 9  9  8 14  9  8  8  4  6  9  5 12  2 12  5  5  5  6  6  5 11 11 
 w  x  y  z 
 4  8  9 10
```

Another alternative using `tidyverse` to use `dplyr` and `ggplot2` functions:

```
library(tidyverse)
freq <- df %>% 
  group_by(data) %>% 
  tally()

ggplot(freq, aes(x = n, y = data)) +
  geom_col()
```

That will produce something like:

[image: barplot of frequencies]

Comment: its showing something like this sir...[link](https://ibb.co/qsHs3YW)

Comment: It is because your y-axis labels are way to long. Two options: (a) truncate the labels so they are not too long, or (b) better look at the results as a table. If you are using RStudio Desktop, then it is as easy as `View(freq)` or save to CSV (`write_csv(freq, "frequencies.csv")`) and then open the CSV in a spreadsheet.